# Referencing python3 in ansible installation

Tags: python-3.x, installation, ansible, ansible-2.x

Q : Referencing python3 in ansible installation

Got both python 2.x & 3.x on the system. In `ansible` install, it shows 2.x. I tried installing `python3` again & then `ansible`, but it doesn't seem to do the trick as per below. Anyway to fix it?.

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.9.27
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/<dir>/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jul  1 2022, 08:35:16) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44.0.3)]

yum install python3-pip
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, ulninfo, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package python3-pip-9.0.3-8.0.1.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

yum install ansible
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, ulninfo, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package ansible-2.9.27-1.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0):

Check doc:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html

To have python3 as the default version of python:
One of the solution is to declare it in your Inventory. Another solution is to use environment variable ANSIBLE_PYTHON_INTERPRETER where ansible runs or define variable ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3 used by ansible playbook.

In short, three possible solutions:
**Solution A:** After adding ansible_python_interpreter to inventory. Example:

```
[all:vars] 
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

**Solution B:** Export ANSIBLE_PYTHON_INTERPRETER=/usr/bin/python3
**Solution C:** Add ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3 to ansible configuration

Comment: Thanks @Ocennia Water for options. Looks like for Solution C , we may have to just put `interpreter_python = <python3path>` in ansible.cfg per doc link you shared?. Q : Does it need restart or something to reflect?

Comment: There are only 4 possible values of the variable interpreter_python.
Read carefully: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html

Globally, use the interpreter_python key in the [defaults] section of ansible.cfg, Use one of the following values:  (1) auto_legacy,  (2) auto, (3) auto_legacy_silent or  (4) auto_silent. So, you cannot put the path of python as the value of this variable.

Comment: Thanks @Ocennia Water for re-iterating on value to use. As you can see from OP, I tried python3-pip install, but still see `which python` printing `/bin/python` and there is symblink present `/usr/bin/python -> python2`. Do I need to first change symb link to point to `/bin/python3` first before I change `interpreter_python = auto_legacy` in `ansible.cfg` file?

Comment: Hi @vinWin, as you are using version 2.9, auto_legacy is the default option of interpreter_python.
IMHO, if you have only one host and if /usr/bin/python is present, yes you can just change the symbolic link to the python3 and it will work. 
However, if you have more complicated inventory, it is better to pick other option so it is ansible de decide what version of python to use.